# Ajuda VBA criar pastas e subpastas e salvar arquivo dentro

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Bom dia pessoal, preciso de ajuda com um código em Vba, basicamente o que eu quero fazer e no diretório que se encontra a pasta de trabalho do Excel ele crie uma pasta chamada "Save", e dentro dessa pasta Save ele pegue o que esta escrito na célula A1 e crie outra pasta com o nome da célula, ate ai tudo bem consegui fazer, mas após ele criar a pasta com o nome da célula A1 eu gostaria que ele criasse dentro dela uma pasta chamada "info" e salvasse o arquivo em .txt dentro da pasta info. as duas primeiras pasta eu consegui mas a 3º pasta e salvar dentro dela não consegui, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
Sub CriarPasta()

'Cria a pasta Raiz aonde esta a pasta de trabalho
     
    Dim raiz As Object, save
        Set raiz = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

            On Error Resume Next

                save = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Save"

    If Not raiz.FolderExists(save) Then
            raiz.CreateFolder (save)
    End If
    
    
'Cria a pasta com o nome da celula A1 dentro da pasta Save
    
    Dim sub_p As Object, subPasta
        Set sub_p = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

            On Error Resume Next

                subPasta = save & "\" & Planilha1.Range("A1").Text

    If Not sub_p.FolderExists(subPasta) Then
        sub_p.CreateFolder (subPasta)
    End If

'Cria uma pasta chamada info dentro da pasta criada com o nome da celula A1

    Dim sub_p1 As Object, info_p
        Set sub_p1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

            On Error Resume Next

                sub_p1 = save & "\" & subPasta & "\" & "info"

    If Not sub_p1.FolderExists(info_p) Then
        sub_p1.CreateFolder (info_p)
    End If

'Salva em txt dentro da pasta info

    Dim Nome As String
    
    Nome = Planilha1.Range("A1").Text
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=save & "\" & subPasta & "\" & info_p & "\" & Nome & ".txt", _
    FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText, CreateBackup:=False


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai ter um problema aqui:

```
    sub_p1 = save & "\" & subPasta & "\" & "info"
```

Porque algumas linhas acima você já definiu que a string `subpasta` é o caminho inteiro da pasta com o nome em A1, dentro da pasta save.
Portanto, a instrução acima transformou a string `sub_p1` em um monstrengo redundante, algo como `c:\...\save\c:\...\save\nome_a1\info`.
Como a string subpasta já contém a string save no começo, creio que é só mudar a instrução acima para:

```
    sub_p1 = subPasta & "\" & "info"
```